# How to get PHP to echo error in a IF statement?

Tags: php, printing, echo

How do i print an error if one of these are not working or rather not display some of these?

```
if ( $what === $toyota ) {
$print = "Camry";
} elseIF($what === $benz) {
$print = "S350";
} elseIF($what === $bmw) {
$print = "M5";
} elseIF($what === $honda) {
$print = "Accord";
} elseIF($what === $acura) {
$print = "mdx";
} elseIF($what === $jaguar) {
$print = "rx";
} elseIF($what === $landrover) {
$print = "rover";
} elseIF($what === $ford) {
$print = "sucks";
} elseIF($what === $gm) {
$print = "garbage";
} elseIF($what === $saturn) {
$print = "sat";
} elseIF($what === $jeep) {
$print = "not sure";
} elseIF($what === $chevy) {
$print = "whatever";
} elseIF($what === $porsche) {
$print = "Panamera";
} elseIF($what === $volkswagan) {
$print = "Passat";

}

print("$print");
}

}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of a switch statement?

Comment: It's possible that a [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is what you're after.

Comment: nonetheless it worked for somethign else i was doing but for some reason its not here.  So anyway to print an error?

Comment: Could you better explain what you need? Also, you could consider using a `switch` instead of all those `if`s.

Comment: What would you consider an error?  The case where `$what` didn't match any of those?  If so, simply tacking an `else{ print('error!'); }` right above your `print("$print");` statement would accomplish that.  [But I agree, you should look into a `switch` statement and pay special attention to the `default` branch.]

Comment: @jedwards i got it to work and found out that my query is fine but for some reason the $print won't work.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should add that `else{ ... }` branch I listed to see if it happens to fall into that.  If it doesn't then my guess is it's falling into the `$what === $honda` branch and setting $print to the empty string.  If that doesn't help come back, there are more debugging steps I can suggest

Comment: @jedwards yes i added that else and thats what i got.  I am going crazy trying to find out whats wrong.

Comment: and that empty "" is just a typo, let me fix it.

Comment: upon checking via shell i got this: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: print in /var/www/domain.com/htdocs/searchpage.php on line 181 /// and this corresponds to the print("$print");

Comment: Okay thats your problem.  `$print` is never set.  You can either add the else branch like I've suggested, and put `$print = "error";` in there, or initialize it before the if-elseif ladder by simply adding `$print = "";` right before the `if($what === $toyota)` line (or both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one of your logic branches is comparing the variable $what to another variable named after a make of car. ie  ($what === $honda)  Where and what are you setting all these different variables to before the logic begins?  Seems like it would be easier to write ($what === "honda") or use a switch statement like everyone recommends.

Also on printing out the variable, you don't need quotes.

Just print($print)
and why not print($what) to see exactly what it is.

Comment: True, you don't need quote, but they won't cause an error either.

Answer (score 2):

```
$map = array($wolskwagan => 'Passat', $chevy => 'whatever');
if (isset($map[$what])) print $map[$what]; else print 'error'; `
```

Answer (score 2):

how about adding a simple `else` at the end ?

```
} elseIF($what === $volkswagan) {
    $print = "Passat";
} else {
    $print = "ERROR !!!";
}
```